# ERROR TypeError: this.paginator is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-pagination

I am using custom pagination in a custom component, which is then being called in a component to display pagination. However I am running into this error.

Custom pagination is working correctly because its usued in another project as well.

Here is my component. Is there anything that I am missing?

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginatorComponent, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginatorComponent;
  data: {
     offset: number;
     limit: number;
  };


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.data$
      .pipe(
        untilDestroyed(this),
        map((settings) => {
          this.data= settings;
          this.paginator.pageIndex = 1;
          this.paginator.pageSize = 10;
          return this.data;
        }),
      )
      .subscribe();
    if (this.paginator && this.data) {
      this.paginator.pageSize = 10; 
      this.paginator.pageIndex = 1; 
      this.matDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    }

    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, could you add more info. For example on which line the `paginator` is undefined?

Comment: @Vazgen I am getting the error from these lines `this.paginator.pageIndex = 1;` and `if (this.paginator && this.data) {`

Comment: Could you add your template? Maybe the `mat-paginator` is inside a ngIf or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using this.paginator inside ngAfterViewInit(), which is not initialised on time.

If you put the In a setTimeout() for delay the error might go away. once you know the issue is an initialisation, and if you don't like setTimeout you can figure out where to load **this.paginator**

```
setTimeout(() =>{
   if (this.paginator && this.data) {
          this.paginator.pageSize = 10; 
          this.paginator.pageIndex = 1; 
          this.matDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        } 
}, 0)
```

Comment: This solution works. However pageSize is not being updated under this.paginator